# Is it a definition or a declaration?

Tags: c

```
struct foo {
   char name[10];
   char title[10];
   int  salary;
};
```

In the above code is it a structure definition or structure declaration ?

I'm learning structures in C, some books says that it is a declaration,  some says it is a definition. So what exactly it is ?

From what I understand a declaration specifies the compiler what the type and name of a variable is, where as a definition causes memory space allocated for the variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a declaration. It declares the type `struct foo`.

> (C99, 6.7p5) "A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. A definition
>   of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that:
>
> — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
>
> — for a function, includes the function body;101)
>
> — for an enumeration constant or typedef name, is the (only) declaration of the
>   identifier."

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct. Your code example is a declaration of a type. In 'C' you can declare a type and immediately use it to define a variable.

So your example is a pure declaration.

And here is an example of declaration+variable definition:

```
struct foo {
     char name[10];
     char title[10];
     int  salary;
} var;
```